# null object reference with automation enabled flex-application at preloader

Tags: apache-flex, testing, automation, functional-testing, ui-automation

We are trying to automate our flex application. After adding automation libraries to our project we get the following exception:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager$/addDelegates()
 at mx.automation::AutomationManager/childAddedHandler()
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
 at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDoneHandler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at mx.preloaders::Preloader/displayClassCompleteHandler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at com.bwin.core.preloading::ApplicationPreloader/onApplicationPreloadingReady()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
 at com.bwin.core.preloading::PreloadingManager/dispatchReadyEvent()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

We are using Flex 3.4 and maven2 to build the application.

Did anybody have this issue with flex-testing?

Thx.

Did anybody

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled automation on a Flex 3.x app, and never saw that exception.  Some more information would be helpful in order to answer the question.

Comment: it is a quiet big application with about 15 modules.
when you test just one module it works. But as this modules are interacting a lot and are depending on each other it would make no sense to test just one.
If you put them together the above mentioned exception occurs.
Do you need more information?

Comment: are the separate modules contained by one big parent module?  are the automation swcs included in each of the modules?

Comment: the separate modules are contained by one big module. 
the automation-swcs are included just once at the end (the compiler removes them at the end if you add them to each module anyway).

Comment: we are using swfloaders to load child modules into a parent module, and include the automation swcs only in the parent.  this has worked well for us.  we are using swfobject to load the parent swf on the web page, and had to set wmode=window (we had some iframe requirements) as well.